# Google cloud build cli - get artifact URL while build is ongoing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I'm using a Google cloud build trigger to build my container image. After pushing a new build (push by git `tag`), I can see it on my Cloud Build history.

[image]

As you can see, the build already has an `artifact` URI (the URI of the image). But, when calling the `gcloud build list` - it's not there:

[image]

It only appears in the IMAGE column AFTER the building is completed.

How to get the `artifact` build while building?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, builds and artifacts are different things.

When you submit `gcloud builds`, you're creating build(job)s that are identified by build IDs.

Builds *may* result in the creation of artifacts (usually -- but not limited to-- container images). It is only during the conclusion of a build that artifacts are generated and so you would not expect these to be available until then.

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args: 
  - build
  - -t
  - "gcr.io/your-project/your-image
  - .
images:
- "gcr.io/your-project/your-image"
```

Or:

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: [STORAGE_LOCATION]
    paths:
    - [ARTIFACT_PATH]
    - [ARTIFACT_PATH]
    - ...
```

Because you specify images|artifacts in your build spec, you can infer (before these are created), where they will result and you could query them directly then. In the case of container images pushed, you may query these using `gcloud container images list`, perhaps (per the above) `gcloud container image list --repository=gcr.io/your-project`

See:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts#artifacts_examples

HTH!